# Convert matlab to java

Tags: java, matlab

i am new in java programming.I need to convert my matlab code to basic java codes not complex like  just using loops and array, i tried several times but i failed.Thanks for helping.Here is my code.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
x = perms(x);
i = 0;
c=1;
for m=1:1:5040;
for n=1:1:6;
if(x(c,n) == (x(c,(n+1))-1))
i = i+1;
break
end 
end
c=c+1;
end

Answer : 2119
```

Comment: `i tried several times but i failed` _What_ have you tried? _What_ doesn't work? _What_ do you expect to happen? _What_ happens instead? Post your code, please.

Comment: Do you have MATLAB Builder JA (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/javabuilder/)? Unless you are manually translating the MATLAB code into Java, that's what you need.

Comment: No,i do not have MATLAB Builder JA,and i can not translating the MATLAB code into Java,i am new at java.

Comment: What is the reason you have to translate your Matlab code to Java? Is it supposed to be an exercise in Java-programming, or do you generally want to translate Matlab to Java (e.g., for performance reasons)?

Comment: ı am taking a lesson at unversity"algorithms and complexity".This is a question that i need to convert to java.

Comment: Where is your _Java_ code? What have you written so far that has failed and how did it fail?

Comment: Question is : we have A,B,C,D,E,F,G the thing is we have to use this letters to create codes with 7 letters.we need to use every letter just once,and the condition is that letters do not follow each alphabetically like AB.. CD..how many codes with 7 letters we create under that condition.I starded in java like that ,and i can not continue.. char a[] = { 'A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D' , 'E' , 'F' , 'G' }
        char code[7]

Comment: It sounds like you are struggling with Java syntax. Maybe you should read a tutorial on Java and it will make things clear. Java also has for loops and if statements (but the syntax is different). I'm not sure what `perms()` does, but I am sure you can do the same in Java. Nobody wants to do your homework for you, but we would like to help when you get stuck, _if you have a specific question_. It is hard to help when we do not know what you are struggling with. Check out [for loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us go through the Matlab code and translate each row into Java. We will be going to need some abstractions, which we will introduce on the go.

First line:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

A vector is assigned to a variable `x`. We could simply say that a vector is an array of integers, but maybe we need some better abstractions later. Let us define a new class `Vector`. Do not confuse it with `java.util.Vector`: There may be multiple classes of the same unqualified name.

```
class Vector {
    private int[] value;

    Vector(int... value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    int apply(int i) {
        return value[i - 1];
    }

    int length() {
        return value.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String prefix = "";
        for (int entry : value) {
            result.append(prefix).append(entry);
            prefix = " ";
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

We are using an array of integers for the internal representation of our `Vector`. Note that you can swap out the internal representation any time as long as it does not leak out into the classe's interface. Hence, we restrict the access of our `value`-member to `private`, meaning only objects of type `Vector` are allowed to access it.

New `Vector` objects are instantiated by calling the constructor `Vector(int... value)`, which takes a vararg integer argument. Internally in Java, varargs are the same as arrays, but they give us syntactic sugar, to instantiate our `x` in the following way:

```
Vector x = new Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

which looks very similar to your Matlab code.

An other thing is that, in Java, arrays are zero-indexed, while Matlab starts indexing at 1. Our `Vector` class defines an `apply`-method, which is supposed to access the `i`-th index. Hence, it returns `value[i-1]`.

Now we want to compute

```
x = perms(x);
```

`perms` returns a matrix, containing all permutations of vector `x`. So we need an other abstraction: `Matrix`.

```
class Matrix {
    private Vector[] rows;

    Matrix(Vector... value) {
        this.rows = value;
    }

    int apply(int x, int y) {
        return rows[x - 1].apply(y);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String prefix = "";
        for (Vector row : rows) {
            result.append(prefix).append(row.toString());
            prefix = System.lineSeparator();
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

`Matrix` is defined very similar to `Vector`, but its internal representation is an array of `Vector`, the rows of the matrix. Again, we define a method `apply` to retrieve an element: this time, it takes two parameters, the row index and the column index.

Side note: It is always good to override the method `toString` which is defined in the top element of Java's type hierarchy: `Object`. You can try to instantiate a `Vector` or a `Matrix` and pass it as argument to `System.out.println` to see how the string representation looks like.

Now we still need to implement `perms` in Java. The method `perms` takes a `Vector` and returns a `Matrix`. I have a very hacked and ugly implementation which I am a bit reluctant to show, but for the sake of a complete answer, here it is:

```
static Matrix perms(Vector vector) {
    int[] indices = new int[vector.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.length(); i++)
        indices[i] = i;
    List<int[]> allPermuationIndices = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    permutation(new int[0], indices, allPermuationIndices);
    Vector[] perms = new Vector[allPermuationIndices.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < perms.length; i++) {
        int[] permutationIndices = allPermuationIndices.get(i);
        int[] vectorValue = new int[permutationIndices.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < permutationIndices.length; j++)
            vectorValue[j] = vector.apply(permutationIndices[j] + 1);
        perms[i] = new Vector(vectorValue);
    }
    return new Matrix(perms);
}

private static void permutation(int[] prefix, int[] remaining, List<int[]> returnValue) {
    if (remaining.length == 0)
        returnValue.add(prefix);
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < remaining.length; i++) {
            int elem = remaining[i];
            int[] newPrefix = Arrays.copyOf(prefix, prefix.length + 1);
            newPrefix[prefix.length] = elem;
            int[] newRemaining = new int[remaining.length - 1];
            System.arraycopy(remaining, 0, newRemaining, 0, i);
            System.arraycopy(remaining, i + 1, newRemaining, i + 1 - 1, remaining.length - (i + 1));
            permutation(newPrefix, newRemaining, returnValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't bother to understand what it is doing. Try writing a clean implementation on your own (or google for a solution).

Now, if we want to reassign our `x`, we run into trouble: The type does not match: We declared `x` to be of type `Vector`, but `perm` is returning a `Matrix`. There are multiple ways to solve this:

- We could declare `Vector` to be a `Matrix`, i.e., change the signature to `Vector extends Matrix`. This solution may make sense, but be careful not to break behavioral subtyping: If a class `B` **is a** class `A`, then `B` must have the same behavior as `A` and can define additional behavior. Look up the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) on the same note.
- We could declare `x` to be of a supertype of both, `Vector` and `Matrix`. Currently, this is `Object`, but we could also define a new common supertype. This solution may however lose our static type safety. For example, if we want to use `x` as argument to `perm`, we need to dynamically cast it to a `Vector`
- We could define a second variable `x2` of type `Matrix` which holds the result. I suggest this solution in this case.

Next, we assign `i = 0;` and `c=1;`, which in Java translates to

```
int i = 0; 
int c = 1;
```

Now, the for-loops:

```
for m = 1:1:5040
    ...
end
```

translates to

```
for (int m = 1; m <= 5040; i++) {
    ...
}
```

The only thing remaining, besides putting it all together, is the if-statement:

```
if(x2(c,n) == (x2(c,(n+1))-1))
    ...
end
```

translates to

```
if (x2.apply(c, n) == (x2.apply(c, n+1) - 1)) {
    ...
}
```

where `apply` is the method we defined on `Matrix`. Note that in Java, `==` will give you strange results if applied to non-primitive types, i.e., everything besides `int`, `byte`, `char`, `double`, `boolean`, and `float`. Generally, you test equivalence using the method `equals` which is defined on `Object`.